is it permissible to create more than one class diagram?
I'm trying to create a simple project and want to implement uml like a class diagram.
According to the sources I studied, class diagrams can only be made once for one project. not made based on features/modules.
However, if I only create one class diagram, I am a little confused when reading my class diagram. Because I created so many classes and interfaces, I had the idea to create several class diagrams based on their features so that they were easier to read.
create class diagrams based on features/modules such as the login feature has a class diagram, the CRUD feature about articles has a class diagram, the CRUD feature for article comments has a class diagram, etc.
So, for those who have worked, done business, or have more knowledge regarding class diagrams, is it normal to create various class diagrams based on features? Or is it a mistake that only one class diagram is allowed for one project?
The answer is related to whether it is permissible to have more than one class diagram in one project

Create as many diagrams as you need. There is no limit.

Yes, you can make as many diagrams as you need.
In all but the most trivial demo projects that would mean more than one diagram.
Diagrams are meant as a means of communication. That means that you target your diagram for your audience.
If you are taking to business users, you might want to show only the entity classes, without attributes or operations.
If you are discussing a certain feature with a developer, you might want to create a diagram with only the relevant classes, attributes and operations.
